# Pandas: Create a table with a “dummy variable” of another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this dataframes

DataFrame A (Products)

```
Cod | Product   | Cost | Date
-------------------------------
18  | Product01 | 3.4  | 21/04
22  | Product02 | 7.2  | 12/08
33  | Product03 | 8.4  | 17/01
55  | Product04 | 0.6  | 13/07
67  | Product05 | 1.1  | 09/09
```

DataFrame B (Operations)

```
id | codoper | CodProd  | valor
-------------------------------
1  | 00001   | 55       | 45000
2  | 00001   | 18       | 45000
3  | 00002   | 33       | 53000
1  | 00001   | 55       | 45000
```

The idea is obtain a "dataframe C" with the column product from "Dataframe B":

DataFrame C Result

```
id | codoper | Product_18| Product_22| Product_33| Product_55| Product_67 |valor
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 00001   | 1         | 0         | 0         | 1         | 0          |45000
2  | 00002   | 0         | 0         | 1         | 0         | 0          |53000
```

So far I only managed to do it from the "DataFrame B":

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['CodProd']).groupby(['codoper'], as_index=False).min()
```

Note: I don't have all products from Dataframe A in the Dataframe of Operations

thanks

Comment: Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to ask a good question.

Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the dummies from `Products` with the dummies from `Operations`. Start by defining the output columns by using a prefix:

```py
columns = ['id', 'codoper'] + [f"Product_{cod}" for cod in A['Cod'].unique()] + ['valor']
```

Then, use get dummies as you're doing above, but use the same prefix from defing the columns. Group by *all columns which perfectly collinear*, i.e. `id`, `codoper`, and `valor`. If these aren't perfectly collinear, than you need to decide how to aggregate them to the level of `codoper`. Finally, reindex using the output columns you previously defined, filling missing values with zero.

```py
pd.get_dummies(B, columns=['CodProd'], prefix='Product').groupby(['id', 'codoper', 'valor'], as_index=False).sum().reindex(columns=columns, fill_value=0)
```

```
  id codoper  Product_18  Product_22  Product_33  Product_55  Product_67  valor
0  1   00001           0           0           0           2           0  45000
1  2   00001           1           0           0           0           0  45000
2  3   00002           0           0           1           0           0  53000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of `merge` and `pivot_table` with some tweaks:

```
(Products.merge(Operations, 
                left_on='Cod', 
                right_on='CodProd',
                how='left')
     .pivot_table(index=['codoper','valor'],
                  values='Product',
                  columns='Cod', 
                  fill_value=0,
                  aggfunc='any')
     .reindex(Products.Cod.unique(), 
              fill_value=False,
              axis=1)
     .astype(int)
     .add_prefix('Product_')
     .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
Cod codoper    valor  Product_18  Product_22  Product_33  Product_55  \
0     00001  45000.0           1           0           0           1   
1     00002  53000.0           0           0           1           0   

Cod  Product_67  
0             0  
1             0
```